# Embedded Viewer API for custom documents

Tags: google-docs-api, google-books, google-document-viewer

I would like to build a web page that list documents that are searchable & scrollable pagewise, this is very similar the the Google Books and within that space, similar to the [Embedded Viewer API.](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/viewer/developers_guide)

I understand the the API works only from the content from Google books, is there an equivalent API that can do the very same thing on the files supplied by the user or application that is not necessarily in the google books.

I also looked at google doc viewer API, features wise it appears basic compared to the embedded viewer API.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you can check out [Google Drive Rest Api](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk). A user can open files , Drive files can be opened from an application independently of the Drive UI. An application can easily fetch and display a list of files with the Google Picker as described in Open files using the [Google Picker](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/integrate-open#open_files_using_the_google_picker).