# PDF view on ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, pdf

I am new to ReactJs. I have tried multiple pdf plugins on ReactJs. But I am unable to show as I want. If anybody has used WPS Office you can see the mobile view option on pdf. So how to do make a dynamic mobile view option for pdf?
Any suggestion would help. Thanks.

Comment: use img tag or canvas tag

Comment: We use google viewer in our project. This should help you.
[Embedded Viewer API for custom documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42931449/embedded-viewer-api-for-custom-documents)